# Starting activity from service not working on different devices *ANDROID*

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, start-activity

I am trying to open an activity (SecondActivity) from the foreground service. This code works fine on my device and I am able to obtain the SecondActivity. But when I try to run this code on another device it doesn't show up the SecondActivity. Please help!! P.S. Both devices are running at the same `API level (API level 28, Android version 9).`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("MyName", getMyName());
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

### My AndroidManifest.xml for SecondActivity goes like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.org.application.SecondActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```

Comment: What is the API level of each device? And, is there any logcat information associated with the failure? If there is, please edit that into your question.

Comment: Both devices are running in same API level (API level 28, Android version 9).

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?